# removeFromSuperview and release memory management

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a MBProgressHUD that I allocate as follows:

```
 self.progressHUD_ = [[[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view] autorelease];
```

if I call removeFromSuperview then would I have to call progressHUD release again? Also if I declare a property with something like this:

```
NSString * title_;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title_;
```

then it is guaranteed that in my dealloc I should have a release on title right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to release it again. Views retain their subviews and release them again automatically when you call removeFromSuperview. As long as the view has been autoreleased when you attach it to the view, it will be released when it is removed from the view.

I didn't quite understand your second question, but yes, you have to release any properties of type "retain" or "copy" in your dealloc statement. You have to write those release statements manually, they aren't added automatically (unless you are using ARC of course, which I strongly recommend).

Comment: well basically if I define a property that is retained in my .h, then I'll have to release it in my dealloc, that's my question

Comment: you're best using self.title_ = nil; in your dealloc rather than [title_ release], because this mitigates the chance that title_ has been previous release yet not set to nil, thus having you release a dangling pointer.

Comment: @paiego I totally agree, but I think that MOST programmers actually do it the way the OP did. Not sure why, though, since setting to nil includes a release automatically.

Comment: That isn't true at all. Setting a property to nil is exactly the same as releasing it and then setting the ivar to nil - it doesn't protect you from previously released pointers. It protects you from *future* releases of the pointer, but in a dealloc there's no risk of future releases anyway.

Comment: Also, by using self.foo = nil; there is a danger that you may be calling a setter method that has additional unexpected side effects, which is why apple explicitly recommend using release statements in dealloc instead of setting the property to nil. Everywhere else in your code you should use the property though, to avoid accidentally leaving a dangling pointer without nilling it out.

Answer (score 1):

If progressHUD_ is a retain property, then you will have to release it in dealloc. However, the nice thing about a retain property is that you only have to set it to *nil* to reclaim the memory; making sure to use "self." before.

```
e.g.

self.<property_name> = nil;

// or in your case

self.progressHUD_ = nil;

// the following will not release it because it's not accessing the property:

progressHUD_ = nil
```

I do not recommend using `[progressHUD_ release]` because it can cause problems. e.g. if elsewhere you had released progressHUD_ and not set it to nil, you may accidentally release a pointer which is no longer allocated (dangling pointer).

I also recommend calling `self.progressHUD_ = nil;` in `viewDidUnload` which is called during low memory conditions and the view is not showing. It doesn't kill your class instance, but just unloads the view. And of course this assumes that you call `self.progressHUD_ = [[[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view] autorelease];` in `viewDidLoad` rather than in `init...`

Answer (score 0):

How is your `progressHUD_` property defined? (btw, the ivar should have a trailing underscore, but not the property name).

In case it is defined as `(retain, whatever)`, you *will* have to release it again:

1. When you create it, its retainCount is +1.
2. When you assign it to your property, its retainCount will be increased by one.
3. When you add it as a subview to the parent view, its retainCount will be increased by one.
4. At some point, autorelease will eventually decrease it by 1, but the view and the property still hold on to it.

So you'll have to either set your property to nil or call `release` on the ivar in your dealloc method.

Also, you probably want to use `copy` instead of `retain` when defining an NSString property. And yes: you'll have to release it either way.

Comment: it's defined as @property (nonatomic, retain) progressHUD_;

Comment: Yes, you have to release it again. Also, you probably want to call your property in your h file "progressHUD" and then say `@synthesize progressHUD=progressHUD_;` in your m file: That way the property is called `progressHUD` and the ivar `progressHUD_`.

Comment: Yes, you always need to use self to access the property. It makes your code clearer to use the underscore only for the ivar, not for the property.

Comment: Absolute retain counts are meaningless.

Comment: @bbum That is correct, I wasn't trying to say that he should actually call retainCount or anything. I just tried to outline that when you add the view to a property of your class that retains it, you still have to release the view in your dealloc method.